# Which should be preferred of Excel/csv for data driven test in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently fetching the data from **Excel sheet** and it works fine too, but as a code it looks weird.So, can I have an alternative which makes **code cleaner**?

If CSV is the better option, please let me know how to iterate the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use CSV data, since, it's easier to parse & requires less coding. At least, you could avoid that weird coding. :)

Comment: Thanks !,  Hope it is not an unusual procedure to follow as I could find Excel sheets dominating for selenium tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should use csv (between Excel and CSV for reason stated by Jonathan Bravetti)or properties file even better

Comment: How can we iterate the rows and fetch the data under each headers?

Comment: @Prabhu Visit following link for demonstration (assuming you are using Java based on tag for this question). [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)